# Conversion of ASTER GDEM data for CFD Analysis

Tags: qgis, convert, 3d, dem

I need to do a computational fluid dynamics (CFD) analysis of wind over a large area of land. I have obtained the necessary tiles from the ASTER GDEM data set (in .tif format) and was wondering how I would go about converting this data into a 3D model which would be accepted by a CFD package such as ANSYS Fluent.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What data formats does ANSYS accept?

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what file format ANSYS uses, but last time when i had to convert DEM files to 3D surface i used FME (Feature Manipulation Engine). (FME is a commercial program by [Safe Software](http://www.safe.com/))
GRASS and QGIS may have feature, usually GRASS has everything, but it's hard to use.

Comment: Importing data into GRASS is nowadays rather trivial, see http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/WxGUI#Import_raster_data

Answer (score 0):

You'll need GIS software (QGIS is OpenSource) to convert raster files into points, then you'll need Civil 3D to create a surface.

To create a solid, use Civil 3D's Extract Solid from Surface command, then convert it to STL.